# How could i use jwt from authorization service in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, jwt

I'm trying to create authorization service.
I have an API service that uses JWT bearer authentication

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<JwtIssuerOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Issuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)];
        options.Audience = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)];
        options.SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(_signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    //...

    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
    {
        AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
        AutomaticChallenge = true,
        TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters
    });

    //...
}
```

with action that returns a token. I want to use this token for authentication in main application. Now it uses cookies and:

```
HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("Cookies", new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity)).
```

How could I inject this token to my app and what configuration it required?